# Django official tutorial for the absolute beginner, absolutely failed!

Tags: python, django

Not that level of failure indeed. I just completed the 4 part tutorial from djangoproject.com, my administration app works fine and my entry point url (/polls/) works well, with the exception that I get this http response:

**No polls are available.**

Even if the database has one registry. Entering with the admin app, the entry shows up the way it should be.

At the end of the tutorial, you change all your hard-coded views by replacing it for generic views on your URLconf. It's supossed that after all the modifications your urls.py ends up like this:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from mysite.polls.models import Poll

info_dict = {
    'queryset': Poll.objects.all(),
}

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^$', 'django.views.generic.list_detail.object_list', info_dict),
    (r'^(?P<object_id>\d+)/$', 'django.views.generic.list_detail.object_detail', info_dict),
    url(r'^(?P<object_id>\d+)/results/$', 'django.views.generic.list_detail.object_detail', dict(info_dict, template_name='polls/results.html'), 'poll_results'),
    (r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/vote/$', 'mysite.polls.views.vote'),
)
```

Using these generic views, It'll be pointless to copy/paste my views.py file, I'll only mention that there's just a vote function (since django generic views do all the magic). My supposition is that the urls.py file needs some tweak, or is wrong at something In order to send that "No polls available." output at /polls/ url. My poll_list.html file looks like this:

```
{% if latest_poll_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for poll in latest_poll_list %}
        <li>{{ poll.question }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No polls are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

It evals latest_poll_list to false, and that's why the else block is executed.

Can you give me a hand at this? (I searched at stackoverflow for duplicate question's, and even at google for this issue, but I couldn't find anything). **Why do I get this message when I enter at http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls?**

Comment: Is that supposed to be easy to understand code. When I did a webapp in assembly/cgi it wasn't that bad :0

Comment: -1: Question title: Absolutely Misleading, Absolute Failure.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You overlooked this paragraph in the 4. part of the tutorial:

> In previous parts of the tutorial, the templates have been provided with a context that contains the poll and `latest_poll_list` context variables. However, the generic views provide the variables `object` and `object_list` as context. Therefore, you need to change your templates to match the new context variables. Go through your templates, and modify any reference to `latest_poll_list` to `object_list`, and change any reference to `poll` to `object`.

Comment: Thank you very much. It's hard to get familiar with django concepts. I was confused between the templates (.html's) and the views.py, I had only changed the context variables on the views, but not the ones in my templates.

Comment: To be fair, the Django tutorial says in section 3: `Load the page by pointing your browser at “/polls/”, and you should see a bulleted-list containing the “What’s up” question from Tutorial 2`. At that point (part three of the tutorial series), you can't see the bullet list, despite it saying you can in part three. It only shows in part four, as Benjamin advises here. So afaics, the tutorial isn't that clear.